# Getting an overflow error and don't understand why

Tags: c, overflow

When I compile the code below, I get an error saying "warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion". And when I run the compiled code, I get an incorrect result, of 0. Why is this and how can I fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  long bigboy = 600851475143;
  int num_of_factors = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < bigboy; i++)
  {
    if(bigboy % i == 0)
      num_of_factors++;
  }
  printf("%d", num_of_factors); 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `sizeof(long)` in your environment? What is the lowest power of 2 which is higher than the value you are trying to assign?

Comment: `600851475143 => 600851475143L` , `for(int i = 1; i < bigboy; i++) => for(long i = 1; i < bigboy; i++)`

Comment: In a 32-bit environment (where `sizeof(long) == 4`, usually), your constant is too long to fit in a `long`; it needs to be stored in a `long long` — assuming `long long` is available.

Comment: @P__J__: Note that constants automatically 'expand' to the minimal type that can represent the value.  Thus, on a C99 or later system, the constant `600851475143` is automatically a `long long` if the value is too big for a `long` (which it might well be).  See: [C11 §6.4.4.1 Integer constants ¶5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4.1p5).

Comment: You are going to need to change the type of `i` too — it should be the same type as `bigboy` (also pointed out by [P__J__](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/p-j) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812858/getting-an-overflow-error-and-dont-understand-why#comment90580605_51812858) — though the chosen type is not reliable/portable.) . Your algorithm is rather wasteful — you don't need to test the values between `bigboy/2 + 1` and `bigboy - 1` (inclusive) as none of them are factors of `bigboy`.

Comment: `#include <limits.h>` ... `printf("largest long is %ld.\n", LONG_MAX);`

Comment: When I tried that, I got an output of "9223372036854775807". That is way bigger than the number that I am working with. @pmg

Comment: @P__J__ I tried those changes, but my program still won't output anything.

Comment: Hint:  Review `for(int i = 1; i < bigboy; i++)`.  What is the largest value `i` can have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get an incorrect result, of 0. Why is this (?)

Insufficiently wide integer math.

2+ changes needed

**Is `long` wide enough?**

`long` may only be 32-bit, then `long bigboy = 600851475143;` is insuffceint to save the constant.  recommend `long long`

```
 long long bigboy = 600851475143;
```

**Is `int i` wide enough?**

`int i` is even more likely to have insufficient width.  `int`, commonly 32-bit, may only be 16 bit.  Should `int` reach its maximum value, a following `i++` is *undefined behavior*.

```
// for(int i = 1; i < bigboy; i++)
for(long long i = 1; i < bigboy; i++)
```

**Is `int num_of_factors` wide enough?**

Why be stingy with integer math?  Suggest using `long long` throughout.

```
// /int num_of_factors = 0;
int num_of_factors = 0;
```

**Performance improvement**

Rather than count to `bigboy`, how about the square root of `bigboy`?

```
long long num_of_factors = 0;
long long i;
for(i = 1; i < bigboy/i; i++) {
  if(bigboy % i == 0) {
    num_of_factors += 2;  // Count both i and bigboy/i
  }
}

// Look for square root
if (i <= bigboy/i) {
  if(bigboy % i == 0) {
    num_of_factors ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: At first I thought, why not save all of those divisions by doing something like `long long littleboy = sqrtl(bigboy);  for (i = 1; i < littleboy; i++) {}`, except that I don't think that there is any guarantee that a `long double` can hold a `long long`. Is that why you chose to do this with `i < bigboy / i` in the loop?

Comment: @DavidBowling No.  FP math of `sqrtl(bigboy)` may render a result just slightly less than a true square root of `bigboy` and should be avoided.  Code is doing `bigboy % i` and the additional cost of doing `bigboy/i` is often free on optimizing compilers - so no "savings" by not using it  .  BTW, a 3rd alternative `for(i = 1; i*i < bigboy; i++) {` can overflow `i*i` and should be avoided.

Comment: I changed `bigboy` to `long long`, `i` to `long long`, and `num_of_factors` to `long long` however my code still does not work at all.

Comment: @JBraha "does not work at all" lacks detail.  Describe the output seen and output expected and how long you waited if code appeared to hang.  Without the `for(i = 1; i < bigboy/i; i++) {` improvement, you original approach may have to wait a _long_ time.  As a debug tip, try code with smaller values like `bigboy = 10;` or `bigboy = 1000;`

Comment: @chux Sorry, by "does not work at all", I meant to say that there is no output, in other words, the `printf()` statement does not appear to be executed. However, I think your point about having to wait a long time must be what's causing the issue.

Comment: @chux Will counting to the square root determine all of the factors of `bigboy`?

Comment: @JBraha Consider smaller values like 100 to self answer "Will counting to the square root determine all of the factors of bigboy".

Comment: @chux sqrt(100) = 10. Factors of 10 are 1, 2, 5, 10. Factors of 100 are 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20, 25, 50, 100. There are a total of 4 factors of 10, and a total of 9 factors of 100. So simply doubling the number of factors for a n's square root will not get to n's number of factors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177959/discussion-between-chux-and-jbraha).